# How to pass a data between different classes defined for tabs in my tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I have this code below, and I want to pass variable `n` in class `Data` to be used in class `tab1` and be used as the `textvariable` of `entry1`. however, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'n'
```

or in general, I want to be able to pass variables between tabs.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = tk.IntVar()

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.minsize(400, 400)
        self.maxsize(400, 400)

        self.my_notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.my_notebook.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.app_data = {}

        lst = [tab1, tab2, tab3]
        for N, F in enumerate(lst):
            tab = F(self.my_notebook, self.app_data)
            self.my_notebook.add(tab, text="Tab"+str(N+1))

        self.data = Data()


class tab1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data

        entry1 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=data.n)
        entry1.pack()


class tab2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data

        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Tab2")
        label2.pack()


class tab3(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data

        label3 = tk.Label(self, text="Tab3")
        label3.pack()

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never create an instance of `Data`. Instead, you're initializing `self.data` to an empty dictionary. You need to create an instance of `Data` and pass that to the tabs.

```
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.app_data = Data()
        ...
```